# Excel 2016 on Win 10 Tablets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

Is there code for capturing screen gestures or screen swipes in Excel 2016 running on tablets? I'm looking for code that I can control with a screen swipe or screen gestures. For example, screen swipe left select a different tab or run code, etc. ?? Trying to simulate tablet behavior in excel 2016 on tablets.

Comment: Could this be accomplished by tracking the cursor? (I don't actually know if there are cursors on tablets...)

Comment: I believe "swiping" is simply interpreted as scrolling in excel. You're looking at implementing gestures in excel? Might have to utilize a different library and implement it through a .NET excel addin, unless it has COM support. People have implemented Intel RealSense into excel this way, so I don't see why you wouldn't be able to with gestures. (Possibly using the windows API)

Comment: Have you actually seen this working in excel? I'd be interested in seeing how it was implemented.

Comment: I don't think user input capturing has ever been part of Excel's object model.  If it's a tablet or hybrid running Windows, what you're looking for is probably the [MSDN library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library) Windows APIs.

Comment: This depends on what tablet you're using. And I'm not sure VBA is the language you'd be using for it.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [TouchMe Gesture Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/touchme-gesture-studio/9wzdncrdg0l8) to create this effect. It has a number of preset gestures, but for a lot of my work in Excel, I just linked the gestures to keyboard shortcuts. In your case you would want something like a 2-finger-swipe-left to correspond to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>pageDown</kbd> and swiping right to correspond to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>pageUp</kbd>

In my observation, the preset options tend to work better than the keyboard shortcuts, but I am satisfied with using gestures to cut/paste/undo/redo in excel.

Just as a note, the gesture studio also requires the the TouchMe Gesture Engine. You get a 30-day free trial period before you either have to purchase the engine, or limit yourself to three gestures.